# Need Help in social engine signup process

Tags: socialengine

HI please help me in the sign up process of social engine,

I need to add a country/state/city cascading dropdowns on my signup process.

I know how to do it in PHP ajax but finding the hard time to do it in this social engine framework.

Can any one help me in this!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin panel. You need menuitem Settings > Profile Questions. Then choose needed profiletype and add question with type 'selectbox'.

If you need cascading dropdown in wider meaning, you may use [jxlib](http://mootools.net/blog/2011/12/26/jxlib-an-introduction/) putting all code into application/modules/User/views/scripts/signup/form/fields.tpl

Answer (score 0):

I have also solved this by using jquery.
You could get the id of the two field involved and then use jquery to add the options of the select field.